# Styling applied to over ride bootstrap styling is missing after a page refresh.(React)

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I applied styling to a select input after applying the "form-select" class which bootstrap provides.
it works fine and the I can modify the styling provided by bootstrap through applying a class of my own but only until I refresh the page,after refreshing, it reverts back to the default styling provided by bootstrap.I'm using module css..Is there a way to fix this issue?..Thanks in advance

react(html)

```
<select className={`form-select ${style.select}`}>
                        <option value="today">Today</option>
                        <option value="tommorow">Tommorow</option>
</select>
```

css

```
.select{
    background: #EFDACD;
    color: #BE6731;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    
}
```